# Live streaming delay in playing around 10 to 15 sec in Android Mobile App

Tags: android, broadcast, rtmp, live-streaming, vlc-android

I have used StreamAxia SDK for broadcast live stream. They are giving "rtmp" url support and its works perfectly fine, within 1 or 2 sec it will start broadcast.

Now, for CDN I have used free version Red5, When I play this URL in VLC player in Android it will take average 10 to 12 sec to play. I have tried many players to render fast but not getting results to play live stream within 2 or 3 secs.

May be some latency problem is there but not identify exactly issue. Please help me to out this or suggest technical flow how to successfully render live stream within 2,3 sec.

Comment: I remember myself having the same issue. What I did about it was to create a custom mediaplayer buffer. This on the other hand has a pretty high min SDK. So I do not really recommend it

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos , thanks for the your view on this , can u explain some more or give me some vision for how to implement custom media player buffer as minimum version is 21.